# Why is this sidebar background color does not change as specified in CSS?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am starting to study ASP.NET with the book "Beginning ASP.NET 4 : in C# and VB" (Imar Spaanjaars - Wrox). Right now I am stuck on "Try It Out" section on page 79: every thing went right except there is no background color for the side bar where it's expected to be gray.

My page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            color: #663300;
        }
        .style2
        {
            color: #FF0066;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="Styles/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="PageWrapper">
        <div id="Header">
            Header Goes Here
        </div>
        <div id="MenuWrapper">
            Menu Goes Here
        </div>
        <div id="MainContent">
            <h1>
                Hi there visitor and welcome to Planet Wrox</h1>
            <p>
                We&#39;re glad you&#39;re <span class="style2">paying a visit</span><span class="style1">
                </span>to <a href="http://www.PlanetWrox.com">www.PlanetWrox.com</a>, the coolest
                music community site on the Internet.</p>
            <p>
                Feel free to have a look around; there are lots of interesting <strong>reviews and concert
                    pictures </strong>to be found here.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="SideBar">
            Sidebar Goes Here</div>
        <div id="Footer">
            Footer Goes Here
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
#Header
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    width: 844px;
    height: 86px;
}

*
{
    font-family: Arial;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#PageWrapper
{
    width: 844px;
}

#MenuWrapper
{
    width: 844px;
}

#MainContent
{
    width: 664px;
    float: left;
}

#Sidebar
{
    background-color: Gray;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
}

#Footer
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    width: 844px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Result (**the sidebar background is expected to be gray**):
[image]

Did I make any mistake, can any one tell me where it is?

Comment: Your browser does not care if your page is build server-side using ASP, or using another language, or if your Grandma is locked into the server room and types the HTTP response by hand. So please tag questions like this appropriately in the future.

Comment: @CBroe: sorry, I am a newbie so I don't know where the mistake is, all I know is that I am learning from an ASP.NET book. I'll be more careful and precise though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Sidebar" != "SideBar"

It is case sensitive

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll be more careful!